# How to display a ContextMenuStrip on a ToolStripMenuItem?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip, toolstripmenu

In Winforms, I want to display a ContextMenuStrip when the user right-clicks on a ToolStripMenuItem.
For example (see the image below), in Firefox there is Bookmarks menu and when we right-click on one of the bookmarks, a context menu item will be displayed.

How could we do it in Windows Form application?

I know we could associate a ContextMenuStrip to a Control (e.g. a Form), but the problem is that ToolStripMenuItem is not a Control.

[image: bookmarks-menu-in-firefox]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a custom ContextMenuStrip and show it while handling the MouseUp event on a ToolStripItem, so basically something like that:

```cs
    toolStripLabel1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(toolStripLabel1_MouseUp);

    private void toolStripLabel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }
```

You can then display different context menus based on the menu item user clicked.

**UPDATE**

Regarding your comment, if you don't like the menu items to disapear when you show context menu, you can iterate through all the tool strip menu items and set `AutoClose` property to `false` (and then back to `true` after showing the context menu):

```cs
    private void toolStripLabel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            AutoCloseDropDowns(menuStrip1.Items, false);
            contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
            AutoCloseDropDowns(menuStrip1.Items, true);
        }
    }

    private void AutoCloseDropDowns(ToolStripItemCollection items, bool autoClose)
    {
        if (items != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var ts = item as ToolStripDropDownItem;
                if (ts != null)
                {
                    ts.DropDown.AutoClose = autoClose;
                    AutoCloseDropDowns(ts.DropDownItems, autoClose);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @bpiec. It works, but when I click the ContextMenuStrip, the ToolStripMenuItem disappeared before the ContextMenuStrip is shown. Could we keep the ToolStripMenuItem displayed as in Firefox's Bookmarks menu?

Comment: You can handle `OnClosing` of `ToolStripMenu` (not item!) and do there `e.Cancel = true` while your `ContextMenusStrip` is visible (make a *flag*). Info is inaccurate, but should helps.

Comment: You can also set `DropDown.AutoClose = false` on all parent items of ToolStripItem before displaying context menu and then set it to true. I will write you an example of that later today.

Comment: @user154321: If that answer helped you please set it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, bpiec. Using DropDown.AutoClose property of         ToolStripMenuItem works very well for me.

Comment: @bpiec this works great to show the contextmenustrip but how can you get the "SourceControl"? meaning, how can you know which toolStripMenuItem was clicked? (since a toolstripmenuitem is not a 'control')

Comment: @Jill: If you assign the same event handler to all menu items than you will have this menu item passed as a `sender` parameter.